# How can I install the BlackBerry v5.0.0 component pack into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-os-v5

I'm trying to install the latest v5.0.0 "beta 2" BlackBerry OS Component Pack into Eclipse 3.4.2 with BlackBerry Eclipse plugin v1.0.0.67, but have hit a few problems.  Has anybody found an easy way to do this?

I had no trouble installing the [v4.5.0 and v4.7.0 Component Packs](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp).

It's rather strange that BlackBerry are shipping new phones with the v5.0.0 OS installed (e.g. a Storm 2 9550 and Bold 9700 that I just bought), and pushing that update to phones whilst [the BlackBerry website](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/devbeta.jsp) still considers the v5.0.0 SDK / Component Packs to be "beta 2"!  If anybody knows when an official non-beta Component Pack is going to be released that might solve my problem...

In case it helps, the problems I've hit so far are:
-Contrary to the implication on [the BlackBerry website](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/devbeta.jsp), the Eclipse ["Software Update..." option](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/updatesite.jsp) for the v5.0.0 Component Pack claims it only works on the v1.0.0 Eclipse BlackBerry plugin, not the new v1.1 one.
-I then tried to install the v5.0.0 Component Pack through the "Software Updates..." menu in Eclipse using the v1.0.0 Eclipse BlackBery plugin.  Once I'd done the 200MB download the install failed with a "Invalid zip file format" error.
-I might just have been unlucky with a corrupted download but I did try it twice, once through "Software Updates..." and once by selecting "Archive" to install the downloaded Component Pack (which unlike v4.5.0 and v4.7.0 was a JAR, not a ZIP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They (rim support) did experience some issue with the zip they have on the site for you to install.
See [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Error-installing-Blackberry-plug-in-for-Eclipse/m-p/80371;jsessionid=4A478B4FB5E2F6B1222CE631925EB03A)

If you see `Unconnected sockets not implemented` just before your `Invalid zip file format`, like:

```
osgi.bundle,net.rim.eide.doc,1.0.0.67.
    Exception connecting to
    https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/auth/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=A7B283681EA93067610F5EE0EEB46A29.
    Unconnected sockets not implemented Exception connecting to
    https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/auth/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=A7B283681EA93067610F5EE0EEB46A29.
    Unconnected sockets not implemented
  Error closing the output stream for
  net.rim.eide.feature.componentpack4.3.0/org.eclipse.update.feature/4.3.0.16
  on repository file:/C:/eclipse/.  Error unzipping
  C:\DOCUME~1\tysonl\LOCALS~1\Temp\net.rim.eide.feature.componentpack4.3.0_4.3.0.169073623197643742544.jar:
  Invalid zip file format Error closing the output stream for
  net.rim.eide.feature.componentpack4.5.0/org.eclipse.update.feature/4.5.0.16
```

, the support mentions:

> The "`Unconnected sockets not implemented`" is caused by a bug in current versions of JDK 1.6.
>   You can work around this by downgrading to JDK 1.5 (modify your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables) to install the plug-ins.  You may need to delete the files in your windows temp folder as well (Eclipse could have cached bad copies of the file).
>   This should be fixed in JDK 1.6 update 14.

(so what version of java are you using?)

As mentioned in the same thread:

> > The following is from the "blackberry plugin for eclipse" download page:
> >
> > It is recommended that users outside of North American or users who have experienced problems with the BlackBerry update site use the links below to manually download and install the components.
>
> Yep, I've read that bit.  That's essentially what I tried to do.  What that doesn't say is you need to remove the update site from your site list before trying to install the manual downloads via the archive function.

Comment: For the record, I never got to retest this as I don't have a requirement to use the v5.0.0 Component Pack any more...

Answer (score 3):

Using Eclipse 3.5.1 and the 1.1 component pack, I had no trouble installing the 5.0 JDE from the 1.1 component pack update site from within Eclipse - ie: using the update site http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java ...
It could be possible that Blackberry has fixed whatever problem you encountered in their latest beta, or the latest version of Eclipse just works better...but at any rate, I hope you've gotten your setup working, but if not, perhaps trying again with the latest versions will fix things!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I never got this working but eventually I will go back and try again.  When I do I will try out the latest Eclipse and plugin versions...

Answer (score 0):

Helpful to me:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Invalid-zip-file-format-trying-to-add-4-7-0-components-to/td-p/411105;jsessionid=32490C8741FEE961B9436E453DFF7430